# Read a Property from an anonymous-typed JSON result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Hi in a Action I create Json data like so:

```
public JsonResult InvoiceLineGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int id)
         {
            ....

                var jsonData = new {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = invoiceLines.Select(............)
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In the method that calls this I want to get the number of records from this data.

Could this be a problem because it's an anonymous type?

I go :

```
var result = controller.InvoiceLineGridData(null, "desc", 1, 10, 7);

result.Data
```

but I can't seem to get the total number of records out. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: where does totalPages come from?

Comment: It's calculated within the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because Data is just an `object`. If you are doing this in the same assembly as your controller, you could create a `dynamic` and get the data from it. But your best bet, if you're actually hoping to use data this way, is to create a real (non-anonymous) type to which you can cast the `Data` in your test method.

```
var jsonData = new InvoiceLineData {
            Total = totalPages,
            Page,
            Records = totalRecords,
            Rows = invoiceLines.Select(............)
        };


var resultData = (InvoiceLineData)result.Data;
// or
dynamic resultData = result.Data;

Assert.AreEqual(10, resultData.Records);
```

As I look at this more, it looks like your data is probably following a specific pattern expected by some kind of general grid control. You would do well to formalize this in a `GridData` class and use that.